# Am I able to give a numeric value to a cell I have filled with a color?

Tags: excel, colors

I am trying to make a color chart for my classroom.  I would like to be able to add these cells together to get totals based on the color the cell given.

I am using cells b3:ao3

If I fill-in a cell with the color yellow I want it to represent 1.

If I fill-in a cell with the color red I want it to represent 2.

I then want to be able to total b3:ao3 with these values.

Maybe I am unable to do this, but any help is appreciated even if it is to tell I can't. :)

Cristy

Comment: Is this using Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be better off entering actual values and use [conditional formatting](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel) to color the cell based on the value. If you don't want the value to be visible, change the format such that the foreground color and background color are the same.

In this scenario, you would populate the cells by entering the number value (1, 2) and they would use conditional formatting to adopt yellow and red respectively.

Finally the formula to sum the values, `SUM(B3:AO3)` uses the values and works as expected, but the visual effect of red and yellow cells is upheld without having to make the values visible as a number.